# How to pass Username and Password in a string while posting in HTTP?

Tags: c, http, url, serialization

I want a URL like char POST/***/?username=***&password=***&action=**. when i enter any valid  username and password 
We tried with hard coded username and password and its working
Explain me how can i do it with some example. 
Why should i use string concatenation here?

Comment: did you mean serialization?

Comment: Maybe `snprintf`is what you are looking for?

Comment: I am doing http socket program in which i want to send username and password for login to server. i am not getting how to pass using http methods on to the server.suggest me something

Comment: suppose consider the following lines . when u hit this u will get something present in that webpage . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201252/how-to-pass-username-and-password-in-a-string-while-posting-in-http?noredirect=1#c                                            Likewise i need to get http://***.com/***?username=***&password=***.         suggest